# How to handle "resteasy.scan is no longer supported. Use a servlet 3.0 container and the ResteasyServletInitializer" Error

Tags: java, wildfly, resteasy

I have some experience with java and I started to teach me REST using RESTeasy using a Wildfly server.
When I deploy my WAR to the server I get the following error or warning:

> resteasy.scan is no longer supported. Use a servlet 3.0 container and the ResteasyServletInitializer

I am using Eclipse and I don't want to use any tool like maven. The jboss doc wasn't useful, at least for me.

Comment: Find a more up-to-date tutorial, or get older version of RESTeasy that fits the tutorial you have.

Comment: Can you give some details about your project setup? Is it maven based? if so what does the pom.xml look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your `JaxRsActivator` class that extends `Application` has to override the `getClasses()` and `getSingletons()` function and the `web.xml` should not contain any Provider.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64691607/2) to the question [How to handle "resteasy.scan is no longer supported. Use a servlet 3.0 container and the ResteasyServletInitializer" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691607/how-to-handle-resteasy-scan-is-no-longer-supported-use-a-servlet-3-0-container) by the OP [Xizz3l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14581340/xizz3l) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>